# Azure Application Exists

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created and deployed an Azure website, which was just to test how it works. So I scrapped the test system and deleted everything for that website off my Azure account.

Now I've re-created the website. When I create a publish profile, everything seems fine:

[image]

But when I click create, I get the error:

[image]

So is it possible to delete and recreate an Azure site on the same subdomain, or is that Url now lost to me forever?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the site usually makes the name available immediately. Can you check on your azure admin site to confirm there is no further cloud service or vm with the same name?

Comment: I'm pretty sure... On the "All Items" screen, I only have 6 items: 2 databases, 2 websites, a Directory, and Visual Studio online. None of those have the same name...

Comment: Weird. I create and delete websites all the time, and recreate them with the same  name, the name is usually available immediately again. Did someone snatch the name? Have you tried browsing to the url and see if something responds back?

Comment: Also, have you tried to create the site again from the Web portal, or powershell? I do remember occasions when the VS tool failed with weird errors

Comment: can't create it via the portal or via visual studio, despite both telling me the name is available.

Comment: Either contact technical support or post it to MSDN forums (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) with your site name and somebody should handle it. Something went probably wrong in the backend during the deletion. Without further details it is hard to tell what is exactly wrong.